# C++ how writing through operator[] works

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int& operator[](int index)
    {
        //Do something and return
    }
};
int main(void) {
    A a;
    a[5] =3;//here
    return 0;
}
```

i want to know where this =3 go to, i know that 5 go to index in function, but where this =3; goes to, it can't activate operator= for sure because i don't have conversation c'tor. Can anyone explain to me how it work, i appreciate it.

Comment: How are the data stored in `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first consider a simple program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int &r = x;

    r = 10;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Here `= 10` goes to `x` because `r` is declared as a reference to `x`

Now consider another simple program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    int & operator []( int i ) { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    int &r = a[0];

    r = 10;

    std::cout << "a.x = " << a.x << std::endl;
}
```

Now " = 10" goes to `a.x` because operator [] returns reference to `a.x`.

```
    int & operator []( int i ) { return x; }
    ^^^^^                               ^^^
```

Of course you could just write

```
a[0] = 10;
```

The effect will be the same because in any case `a[0]` (you may use any integer number here instead of 0; 0 is used only for exposition) returns reference to `a.x`.

Relative to your code snippet =3 goes to what the operator call

```
a.operator []( 5 )
```

refers to.

In my example it refers to data member x of struct A. In your example it is unknown because you did not show how the operator is defined that is what is refered by the return referenced type of the operator.

Comment: This was great explanation, but why for example if i change return value for operator[] to int, it will give error?
 int operator[](int index)
 {
  //
 }

a[5] =3;//int r = a[5]; // r=3

I know if this works it will just edit the r value without editing x in your example but why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Saif When you changed the return type of the operator to int then the operator returns a temporary object that is a copy of data member a.x. Only constant references may be bind to temporary objects.  Of course if you use a non-reference declaration like int r then there is no problem. But it is not a reference and the return type of the operator also does not refer to some object.